# BT wifi Internet router not detecting S9K miner

Tags: cryptography, asicminer

I am mining crypto via GPU & ASIC miners. I recently bought an S9K Antminer which powers on perfectly fine; however as we all know, it needs to connect to the internet via an ethernet cable. This is where I have an issue.
When I connect my laptop or my GPU mining rig to my router via ethernet cable both devices are recognized on the router's 'BT Smart Hub' web interface, internet also works. However, when I connect my S9K to the router via ethernet the 'BT Smart Hub' web interface does not recognize nor detect the connection. I know its not the cable because of the examples above and because I attempted connecting the S9K to my GPU mining rig via ethernet cable and my computer recognized the connection straight away ( of course it had no internet, but still showed "Unidentified network via ethernet cable") I tried to call BT but the guy said unfortunately he has no expertise to address my issue, since I confirmed the router detected two other different devices (laptop / gpu mining rig) so he suggested I find an expert. Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Determine your home's private IP network information. It's likely somewhere in 192.168.x.y range, or perhaps 10.x.y.z

Antminer has instructions for determining the S9K's IP address (https://support.bitmain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025765073-How-to-set-up-a-new-S9-SE-S9k) and to program its network and operating parameters.

It is likely the Antiminer is trying to get an IP address assigned  via DHCP; see if the router has an attached device list, possibly listing MAC addresses of attached devices. Antminers should have Bitmain's prefix, "E0-A5-09-xx-xx-xx". If you can see a device with a MAC address matching this prefix, that will be your S9K.
You may have to temporarily re-configure a laptop connected via ethernet directly to the Antminer to be able to access and reprogram the Antminer on a compatible browser to match your BT (British Telecom) router's private home network.